Nginx ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
Пытаюсь сделать переадресацию на резервный поддомен в случае недоступности главного.
upstream backend {
    server localhost:281;  # Основной сервер
    server reserve.mydomain.com backup;  # Резервный сервер
}

server {
    listen 1443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:1443 ssl http2;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.myssl.xyz/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.myssl.xyz/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;  # Использование upstream
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        
        proxy_read_timeout 10s; # Тайм-аут ожидания ответа от сервера
        proxy_send_timeout 10s; # Тайм-аут на отправку данных к серверу

        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_502 http_503 http_504; # Условия перехода на резервный сервер
    }
}

В случае доступности 281 порта, сайт отображается корректно, но в случае недоступности, при подключении появляется уведомление
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
Страница недоступна
Сайт mydomain.com выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз.


Логичный вопрос — что такое reserve.mydomain.com и что он отвечает на запрос?

reserve.mydomain.com это поддомен главного домена, который расположен на другом сервере. Это версия главного сайта с ограниченным функционалом, но это не столь важно.

И он точно-точно никогда ни на каких запросах не редиректит обратно на mydomain.com?

Точно, это html файл который выводит пользователю только наименование домена.

И он точно-точно не пытается редиректить с http на https, например?

Вне зависимости от настроек редиректа на reserve контекст ошибки не меняется. Я пробовал с редиректом с http на https и без него, но результат не менялся, mydomain.com выдавал туже самую ошибку.

Ну, при таких вводных проблема не воспроизводится, я в качестве резервного прописал свой сайт (убрав в нём https-редирект и проверку домена) и он успешно открылся

Я правильно понял, что проблема не в конфигурации nginx? Если это так, остаётся только вариант с тем, что проблема заключается в cloudflare...

Если вы имеете в виду, что reserve.mydomain.com находится за cloudflare, и при этом вы отправляете на него из nginx запрос через http и с неправильным доменом proxy_set_header Host $host; — логично ожидать, что cloudflare не поймёт, что вы от него вообще хотите

Господи.. я не ожидал что проблема и ошибки настолько тупые... большое спасибо за помощь!
